# working with dynamic controls in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

I have two controls in a table row, when I click on the button I'm adding a new row with these two controls.
The problem is that when I click on the button to add controls it is adding, but the jQuery code is not fired for new controls.

Where is the problem with the code?

```
 <table id="tblIncidentProductOption">

 <tr>
 <th>Product</th>
 <th>Quantity</th>
 </tr>
 <tr class="Row">
 <td><input type="text" name="p0" id="p0" value="0"/></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="q0" id="q0" value="0"/></td>
 <td>
 <div data-corners="true" id="deldev"  class="ui-btn ui-shadow
 ui-btn-corner-all   ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-a"
 aria-disabled="false">
 <span class="ui-btn-inner"><input type="hidden"
 id="d0" class="ui-btn-hidden" name="d0"
 onclick="$(this).closest('tr').remove();" />
 <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">
  </span>

  </span>

  </div>                       

    </td>

      <td class="tot">
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="t0"  value="0" class="total" />
      </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
The jQuery code for the button click:

$('#btnAddOption').on('click', function () {
    var $tr = $('#tblIncidentProductOption')
        .find("tr:last").clone();

    $tr.find("input").attr("name", function () {
        var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
        return parts[1] + ++parts[2];
    }).attr("id", function () {
        var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
        return parts[1] + ++parts[2];
    }).attr("value", "0");
    //  $tr.find("td input").each(function () { $(this).attr("value", "0");});
    $tr.find("td:nth-child(3)").show();
    $tr.find("input[type='hidden']").attr("type", "button");

    $('#tblIncidentProductOption')
        .find("tr:last").after($tr);
});
```

The jQuery code for combining two text box value and adding two hidden fields:

```
$('#tblIncidentProductOption  tr').each(function () {
    $("input").each(function () {
        $(this).keyup(function () {
            var sum = "";
            var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');
            var total = "";
            $(thisRow).find("td:not(.tot) input").each(function () {
                sum = sum + '-' + $(this).val();
            });
            sum = sum.slice(1).slice(0,-1);
            $(thisRow).find(".total").val(sum);
            $('input[class*="total"]').each(function () {
                total = total + '|' + $(this).val();
            });
            //$('#tblIncidentProductOption tr').each(function () {
            //    alert('tr');
            //    $('td:nth-child(4) input').each(function () {
            //        total = total + '|' + $(this).val();
            //    });
            //});
            total = total.slice(1).slice(0,-1);
            $('#result').val(total);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding your event Handlers to each element that exists when your second javascript snippet is executed.  So, when you add new elements you haven't bound an event handler to them.  You can fix this, simplify your code, and likely improve your performance by switching to event delegation.  I can't get a fiddle up and running with what you provided but I would suspect changing these three lines:

```
$('#tblIncidentProductOption  tr').each(function () {
    $("input").each(function () {
        $(this).keyup(function () {
```

to:

```
$('#tblIncidentProductOption').on('keyup', 'input', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
```

and then replacing references to "this" with target may do the trick.

The short and sweet of it is, now, instead of binding handlers to each input, you bind a handler to a parent element and react whenever a keyup event bubbles through whose target matches the 'input' selector.

Comment: when i add new controls via j query they are holding previous values.how can i clear the content new controls..

Comment: If you could provide more complete markup that actually includes the buttons it would be much easier to assist.

Comment: I don't think the logic is what you are expecting, but this fiddle shows the delegated version handling the keyup events: http://jsfiddle.net/esujD/

Comment: in the fiddle the third button taking the same value 8-8

Comment: i want the third button value as product-quantity

Comment: at last i want to display total value in another text box like this 1-2|3-4|2-4|... as we add controls